# Sort by multiple attributes with Salat for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, scala, salat

I try to perform a query on a MongoDB with Salat. The query should sort the result set by two attributes. I haven't found any examples. Sorting with a single MongoDBObject works as expected.

```
val results = dao
  .find(MongoDBObject.empty)
  .sort(orderBy = MongoDBObject("attribute1" -> 1))
  .skip(0)
  .limit(10).toList
```

How to combine two MongoDBObjects so that it is evaluated by `orderBy`? For example if my priority one sort is by attribute1, ascending and my secondary sort by attribute 2, ascending.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can build your sort object as following:

```
val sort = MongoDBObject("attribute1" -> 1) ++ ("attribute2" -> -1)
```

And do the query:

```
val results = dao
  .find(MongoDBObject.empty)
  .sort(orderBy = sort)
  .skip(0)
  .limit(10).toList
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the following change:

```
val results = dao
  .find(MongoDBObject.empty)
  .sort(orderBy = MongoDBObject("attribute1" -> 1, "attribute2" -> -1))
  .skip(0)
  .limit(10).toList
```

Now you'll sort with precedence on attribute1 in ascending order and on ties it will go to attribute2 in descending order.  This allows you to do everything in one line instead of creating an intermediate value which would be required in the list concatenation answer.